# Mala deteccion de bordes - OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy tratando de "*escanear*" una imagen para luego aplicarle unas transformaciones y poder sacar texto de esta imagen, sin embargo al hacer el contorneado de bordes, no tengo el resultado esperado, esto debido a falsos positivos que se detectan en la imagen.

**Codigo**

```
image = cv2.imread('wasap.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(gray,10,150)
canny = cv2.dilate(canny, None, iterations=1)
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:1]

for c in cnts:
    epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(c, True) 
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
    print(approx)
    if len(approx) >=4: #== 4
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], 0, (0,255,255),2)
        cv2.circle(image, tuple(approx[1][0]), 7, (255,0,0),2 )
        cv2.circle(image, tuple(approx[0][0]), 7, (0,255,0),2 )
        cv2.circle(image, tuple(approx[2][0]), 7, (0,0,255),2 )
        cv2.circle(image, tuple(approx[3][0]), 7, (255,255,0),2 )

        pts1 = np.float32([approx[1][0], approx[0][0], approx[2][0], approx[3][0]])
        pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[270,0],[0,310],[270,310]])
        M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
        dst = cv2.warpPerspective(gray, M, (270,310))
        cv2.imshow("dst", dst)

        #texto = pytesseract.image_to_string(dst,lang="spa")

        # with open("texto.txt","w") as f:
        #     f.write(texto)
        # print(texto)
```

Como dije esto no retorna 4 bordes, sino mas, esto es visto gracias a lo que nos devuelve la variable `approx`

```
[[[  1   9]]
 [[  0 243]]
 [[ 85 245]]
 [[ 45 266]]
 [[199 264]]
 [[ 97 258]]
 [[196 246]]
 [[176  13]]
 [[ 24  13]]
 [[ 17  49]]]
```

**Imagen de entrada**

[image: Imagen_de_entrada]

**Imagen Canny**

[image: imagen_canny]

**Imagen con los bordes**

[image: Image_contourner]

**Imagen transformada**

[image: image_transform]

Como se ve en la imagen se detectan mal los bordes, y por ultimo y mas evidente la imagen transformada no es correcta, lo cual impide la detección de caracteres. ¿Cómo podría detectar y contornear bien los bordes?, se podria eliminar algunos bordes no correspondientes?. Please

Comment: hola amigo si quieres ayuda nos vemos en discord haya te puedo dejar una mejor explicación de lo que preguntas: https://discord.gg/VbvKbyBT